# need help with xsl transformation - unwanted text

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to match just the  secondary-content xml tag. but it's outputting text "/ Main cotnent goes here." Why is it outputting text from the masthead and maincontent tag?

xmL:

```
<xml>
  <system-data-structure>
    <mastheads>
      <masthead>
        <image>
          <path>/</path>
        </image>
        <alt/>
      </masthead>
    </mastheads>
    <maincontent>
      <content>
        <p>Main content goes here.&#160;</p>
      </content>
    </maincontent>
    <secondary-content>
      <title>
        <h2>Secondary Content Title</h2>
      </title>
      <block>
        <path>/</path>
      </block>
      <content>
        <p>Secondary main content goes here.&#160;</p>
      </content>
    </secondary-content>
    <secondary-content>
      <title></title>
      <block>
        <content>
          <div class="aux-content-box">
            <h2 class="aux-content-box">More Information</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Air Force Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Army Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Coast Guard Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Marine Corps Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Navy Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">National Guard State Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">National Guard Federal Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Reserve Tuition Assistance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">US Department of Veteran Affairs: Tuition Assistance Top-Up Program</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </content>
        <path>/web/current-students/military/military-links-nav</path>
        <name>military-links-nav</name>
      </block>
      <content/>
    </secondary-content>
  </system-data-structure>
</xml>
```

xsl:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
      <xsl:template match="/system-data-structure">

      <xsl:apply-templates select="secondary-content" />
       </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="secondary-content">
        Found a learner!
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
/ Main content goes here.  Found a learner! Found a learner!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked question. It's due to XSLT's [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) that implicitly drive the processing of various nodes.

Override the built-in template for text nodes with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Comment: Built-in templates are working there, but the problem can not be solved using your suggestion. See other answers.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the behaviour is with your first template matching line

```
<xsl:template match="/system-data-structure">
```

In your XML, the root element is **xml**, not **system-data-structure**. This means it doesn't match anything, and this is why the built-in templates are kicking in as described in the previous answer.

Try replacing the above line with this...

```
<xsl:template match="/xml/system-data-structure">
```

This should then yield the following output

```
Found a learner!  Found a learner!
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your first template, you're trying to match `system-data-structure` at the root level. However, `xml` is the root level in your XML example. Change the match to `/xml/system-data-structure`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/xml/system-data-structure">  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="secondary-content" />
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="secondary-content">
    Found a learner!
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```